# how to get apikey from the minikube cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have created minikube cluster. I have to run my automation script in the minikube for testcases using pytest. I have to pass service account. How to get the it? Anyone can please help?

Comment: what the automation script will do? Which tool you are using to run it?

Comment: it runs testcases using pytest

Comment: I need to pass api key of the user

Comment: Are you talking about service account ? There is nothing called as `api key` in kubernetes

Comment: apikey in the sense token I'm asking

Comment: yes I'm asking about serviceaccount

Answer (score 1):

While running minikube add extra flags:

```
minikube start \
    --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-signing-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.key \
    --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.pub \
    --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-issuer=api \
    --extra-config=apiserver.service-account-api-audiences=api,spire-server,nats \
    --extra-config=apiserver.authorization-mode=Node,RBAC \
    --extra-config=kubelet.authentication-token-webhook=true
```

Take a look: [minikube-sa](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7855#issuecomment-628287907), [kubernetes-psat](https://github.com/spiffe/spire-examples/blob/f98e8ee3b6e528f3e0daa4eec309967a6e2998ff/examples/k8s/simple_psat/README.md#configuration).